# Vue and Firebase: Prevent some `data` from being saved to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I have a component that gets synced to Firebase. I want instances of the component to have some properties that do *not* get synced to Firebase:

```
Vue.component('myComponent', {
    data: function(){
        return {
            title: '',
            isShown: false
        }
    }
});
```

`title` should be saved to the database, but `isShown` should not since it's used just to show and hide the element in the browser.

Is there a way of adding reactive properties to a component instance without them being synced to Firebase?

Comment: Just a guess but how about `ref.set({ title: this.title })`? Without seeing how you're "syncing" to Firebase, it's impossible to provide anything more

Comment: There are rather a lot of properties in addition to `title`, so this doesn't seem very DRY.

Comment: I'm using [Vuefire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire).

Comment: I'm not aware of any auto-syncing of all component `data` in Vuefire. Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Only firebase data references are synced to Firebase.  Entries in the `data` object will be reactive within Vue, but will not by default be synced to the server.   Component properties may be firebase references or plain clientside data objects, depending on what the parent component passed down in the prop.

Some examples:

```
var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
var db = firebaseApp.database();

Vue.component('myComponent', {
  data: function() {return {
    foo: true,                      // <-- 'foo' will not be synced
  }},
  firebase: function() {return {    // (vuefire hook)
    bar: db.ref('path/to/bar')      // <-- 'bar' will be synced
  }},
  mounted: function() {return {
    this.$bindAsArray('baz',db.ref('path/to/baz')) // <-- 'baz' will be synced
    // ($bindAs is also from vuefire)
  }},
  props: [qux] // <-- depends on what the parent component passed down 
}
```